# How to work with nested Shadow root elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium, dom, shadow

Just an update. The question was closed with links to some previous post. I have tried those already and they don't work anymore. Both the post use "expandRootElement" method to expand the nested root element. That's the one I ma using and is not working. Any help is appreciated.

My web application contains nested shadow root elements something like this (Sorry I can't share my original code)
[image]

Here is my code that I was using to work with the element (Download button in this case)

```
public WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    return ele;
}
```

It was working fine till yesterday using Chrome 95 on Selenium 3.14. Today I upgraded to Chrome 96, updated the chromedriver to match that and Selenium to 4.0.0. The same code is now not working with this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.ShadowRoot cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (org.openqa.selenium.remote.ShadowRoot and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at supportFunctions.BaseClass.expandRootElement(BaseClass.java:905)
    at com.testSL.pageObject.ContentPage.addItemNew(ContentPage.java:517)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.publishPerfTest(TC_PerformaceTest.java:61)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.publishPerfTestMain(TC_PerformaceTest.java:42)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.prefTestMain(TC_PerformaceTest.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I tried the same with FireFox too (version 94) and get this error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'KMATHUR2', ip: '10.28.51.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [c01f9386-ba90-44f7-b08a-5d948d74e324, executeScript {script=return arguments[0].shadowRoot, args=[{ELEMENT=78ddc289-1225-4a53-9d6d-0c81444ca2e3, element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=78ddc289-1225-4a53-9d6d-0c81444ca2e3}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 94.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20211028161635, moz:debuggerAddress: localhost:54877, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.30.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 3468, moz:profile: C:\Users\kuld6666\AppData\L..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:54877/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 85, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c01f9386-ba90-44f7-b08a-5d948d74e324
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:493)
    at supportFunctions.BaseClass.expandRootElement(BaseClass.java:909)
    at com.testSL.pageObject.ContentPage.addItemNew(ContentPage.java:517)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.publishPerfTest(TC_PerformaceTest.java:61)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.publishPerfTestMain(TC_PerformaceTest.java:42)
    at com.testSL.testCases.TC_PerformaceTest.prefTestMain(TC_PerformaceTest.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Check out [this bug report](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10050) with workaround. This comment is made by [@derRichter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6104616/derrichter), I copied it from his edit as he can't post comments because of the small rating.